# how to set the selected date in daterangepicker on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) with the option `singleDatePicker: true`. I want to set the selected date in daterangepicker based on the text-box value when ever text-box is clicked/focus/tap. But having trouble in setting it.

Here is my code: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/nmzqw5ve/)

```
$(document).find('input.dob).each(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    var dtrOptions = {
        showCustomRangeLabel: false,
        showDropdowns: true,
        singleDatePicker: true,
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 10,
        startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
        locale: {
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A'
        },
        "parentEl": "#schedulingModal",
        "drops": "auto"
    };

    var dtp = $('#' + $t.attr('id')).daterangepicker(dtrOptions);
    $t.on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, Picker) {
        $t.val(Picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'));
    });
    $t.on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, Picker) {            
        $('#' + $t.attr('id')).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate($t.val());
        });
    $t.on('focus', function () {
        //$('#' + $t.attr('id')).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate($(this).val());
    });        
});
```

Comment: I've always found the following more useful than the range picker for what you are looking to do. Please check if this fiddle helps: https://jsfiddle.net/pe6skvuL/

Comment: @PriyankPanchal how can we selected date on the fly and how can we use calendar with time selection?